# Add-ADGroupMember cannot find an object with identity

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script to import a large number of users into AD.

One of the items is to add the users to AD security groups according to their program number. Mostly, this is working well, unless I misspell something, or other simple human errors. However, we have 2 security groups everyone must be added to, and while the `Add-ADGroupMember` works perfectly on one, it can't find the other group. This is the the script I'm using:

```
$Users = Import-Csv "C:\PSScripts\Create\users.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users) 
{  
    $AccountName = $User.firstname + "." + $User.lastname
    $Program = $User.Program
    $HomeDrive = 'H:'
    $UserRoot = '\\twgeneral\homedrive\'
    $HomeDirectory = $UserRoot+$AccountName
    Set-ADUser $AccountName -HomeDrive $HomeDrive -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory
    If ($AccountName -eq $AccountName)
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ALL_USERS" -Member $Accountname
    } 
    If ($AccountName -eq $AccountName)
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "000-All users" -Member $Accountname
    }
}
```

And I get this error returned:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '000-All users' under:     'DC=*****,CD=local'.
At C:\psscripts\create\Groups.ps1:15 char:23
+     {ADD-ADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity "000-All users" -Member $Accountname
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: <000-All users:ADGroup> [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: '000-All users' under: 'DC=*****,DC=local'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Yet I can add users to the 000-All users group using the ADUC graphic interface.

Similarly, I'm running a script prior to this one, creating users with SAM; Display Name; Exch. E-mail Account; Password; and specific OU within the domain, and it executes without errors, I can go into the graphic interface and see the user right where they are supposed to be with all pertinent details configured, yet some of the users return the same 'object not found' error when I try to execute the part of the groups script that DOES work, the ALL_USERS group. Specifically, it's users who have a hyphenated last name, ex: Markiem-Chalmers, or Tatem-Brown.

I know that the syntax for the `Add-ADGroupMember` is correct, because I copied and pasted from the prior string, which does execute properly, only changing the name of the group from ALL_USERS to 000-All users, and I've double, triple, quadruple checked that the spelling is correct. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Can you verify "000-All users" is the SAMAccountName of the group in question? Have you tried using the DN of the group?

Comment: Oh boy, I feel sort of foolish now. Changed the group name to the pre-win2k, took care of it right away. Same with the hyphenated last-name users, it truncated the last name, and sheered off characters. Which leads to another problem- I can't go in and alter the last names of over 50 people in order for it to execute the script correctly. How can I modify the script to pull the entire name that's listed in the csv, not the truncated pre-win2k version? I thought that by specifying the '$accountname' as the user's first and last name as specified in the respective columns in the csv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reply to the question you brought up in the comments:

`Add-ADGroupMember` can only search by DN, SAM, GUID, or Sid; you can't search by Name or other properties through that cmdlet directly.

You *could* run a `Get-ADUser` on the entries in the CSV to pull the SAM using Name or otherwise, but if the issue is that the SAM is truncated, why not substring?

```
$limit = #The length a name can be before it gets truncated
if($AccountName.Length -gt $limit)
{
    $AccountName = $AccountName.Substring(0,$limit)
}
```

Comment: The character limit is 20 characters, so i'd write it $Limit = 20   or would I write it $Limit = #20  ?

Comment: `$limit = 20`. `#` is the comment symbol - I was just using it to explain `$limit`.

Comment: It's still telling me it can't find the object, so I must have utilized the substring wrong? I've never used one before, still pretty new to powershell.

Comment: $AccountName = $User.firstname + "." + $User.lastname
    $Limit = 20
    $Program = $User.Program
    $HomeDrive = 'H:'
    $UserRoot = '\\twgeneral\homedrive\'
    $HomeDirectory = $UserRoot+$AccountName
    SET-ADUSER $AccountName -HomeDrive $HomeDrive -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory
    If ($AccountName.Length -gt $limit)
    {$AccountName = $AccountName.Substring(0,$Limit)
    }    
    If ($AccountName -eq $AccountName)
    {ADD-ADGroupMember -Identity "ALL_USERS" -Member $Accountname
    }

Comment: How can I get group `CN=ROLE_AGENT,OU=PROFILES,OU=NSI PRODUCTION,DC=xxxxx,DC=net` ? Maybe `$ROLAGENCIA_GRUPO = (Get-ADGroup -Server $ServerAD 'ROL_AGENCIA').DistinguishedName`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both! That did the trick! Final code was with changing the column to GroupName

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\list.csv"

foreach ($item in $list)
{
Get-ADGroupMember -identity $item.GroupName | select name | Export-csv -path c:\Temp\$($item.GroupName).csv -Notypeinformation
}
```