# I don't know why I can't find members of this group

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

```
$Group = "IT Staff"
Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group |
  select @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"}, Name |
  Export-Csv C:\Srptupd\Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I get an error that says:

```
 Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'IT
 Staff' under: 'DC=example,DC=com'. At
 exportmembers.ps1:5 char:1
 + Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group |
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IT Staff:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

---

I am able to locate "IT Staff" when I search for it in AD. I don't know why it's not working.

**EDIT:**
Problem solved with using **Pre-Windows 2000** name

Comment: Does Get-ADGroup 'IT Staff' returns any result?

Comment: Not with code. I can find it using AD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add-ADGroupMember cannot find an object with identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718962/add-adgroupmember-cannot-find-an-object-with-identity)

Comment: you have a domain named example.com or is just a message edit for posting it on the internet?

Comment: Check the group's `SAMAccountName` or "Pre-Windows 2000 group name" and search for that, you should get the group object. This happens if SAM account name for the group is different from display name.

Comment: The Pre-Windows 2000 name is "IT Staff - DL". I just tried with the Pre-Windows 2000 name and it worked. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of this the get the SAMAccountName, then re-run your code:

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | ? {$_.Name -match "IT Stuff"} | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | ? {$_.Name -match "Stuff"} | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```

one of them should get your sam account name...

Comment: This should work indeed, if you'd not mistype "Staff" as "Stuff".

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-ADGroup`, as well as other `Get-AD*` cmdlets, gets groups by searching their `sAMAccountName` attribute, while you are apparently giving it a `DisplayName` or `Name` attributes, that may differ from that listed above. It is usually not so, but some actions against AD object can make those attributes differ from each other. So you should find out that group's `sAMAccountName` value, and if it's different from displayed name, use that value in `Get-ADGroup` call.